# Javascript - Multiple Form Display Issues

Tags: javascript, forms, load, hide

So I'm working on a form that when you click it it brings up another form, then another, etc etc.

For the example, this is what I have so far:

```
<head>
<script langauge="javascript">
function showGeneral(){
    document.getElementById('general').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('colors').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('domain').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('details').style.display="none"; 
}

function showColors(){
    document.getElementById('general').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('colors').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('domain').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('details').style.display="none";  
}

function showDomain(){
    document.getElementById('general').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('colors').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('domain').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('details').style.display="none"; 
}

function showDetails(){
    document.getElementById('general').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('colors').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('domain').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('details').style.display="block"; 
}

</script> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="general" name="general">
<h1> General </h1>   
<form id="general" name="general">
    Name <input type="text" id="frm1txt1" name="frm1txt1"/> <br>
  Email <input type="text" id="frm1txt2" name="frm1txt2"/> <br>
  <input type="button" id="frm1btn1" name="frm1btn1" value="Continue" onclick="showColors();"/> <br>
</form>
</div>



<div id="colors" name="colors" style="display:none">
<h1> Colors </h1>   
<form id="frm2" name="frm2">
    Green? <input type="text" id="frm2txt1" name="frm2txt1"/> <br>
  Red? <input type="text" id="frm2txt2" name="frm2txt2"/> <br>
  <input type="button" id="frm2btn1" name="frm2btn1" value="Continue" onclick="showDomain();"/> <br>
</form>
</div>


<div id="domain" name="domain">
<h1> Domain Name? </h1>   
<form id="frm1" name="frm1">
    Yes <input type="text" id="frm1txt1" name="frm1txt1"/> <br>
  No <input type="text" id="frm1txt2" name="frm1txt2"/> <br>
  <input type="button" id="frm1btn1" name="frm1btn1" value="Continue" onclick="showDetails();"/> <br>
</form>
</div>

<div id="details" name="details">
<h1> Describe Your Order </h1>   
<form id="frm1" name="frm1">
    Img <input type="text" id="frm1txt1" name="frm1txt1"/> <br>
  kk <input type="text" id="frm1txt2" name="frm1txt2"/> <br>
  <input type="button" id="frm1btn1" name="frm1btn1" value="Finish" onclick="showGeneral();"/> <br>
</form>
</div>

</body>
```

The functions work fine - but the problem is it displays all the forms at on page refresh/load. How do I make it so just the first one displays when you load that page?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page loads there is no call to any of the JS functions so none of them are being processed and all your forms are displayed.  You need to add an explicit call to one of the functions.  So to display the first form only you'd need to add

```
showGeneral();
```

In your script block (after the showDetails() function for example).

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate.
I'm sort of confused as to where and how I should put in:
`showGeneral();`

Can you give me an example please?

Thanks

Comment: Sure - you have a few options.  If you just pu the showGeneral(); line anywhere between the start and end <script> tags then it will be called once that line is reached when the JS is parsed.  Therefore if you put it as the last line of code in your script tag then the functions will be created and then the showGeneral function will be called once that last line is read.  Or you could put it in an event such as the onLoad event of the body tag, which is called when the page is done loading.  To do that, simply change your opening body tag to <body onload="showGeneral();">

Answer (score 0):

You need to tie up each of your JS functions with an event, so that the function is called when the event is triggered.

From what I understood of your question, you need to have an onclick event handler associated with some element of your form - so that when the first one is clicked, it calls the appropriate function for the second form and so on. Also, initially just set the first form to be visible (through your CSS).